# SwiftUI Custom Rounded RectangleShape

Tags: swiftui, path, drawing, shapes

Does anyone know how to make a shape like this?
[image]

I followed [apples tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) and came up with this but it seems overly complicated for what I want to do and not perfectly rounded. It also seems hard to implement and maintain to me. Seems like there is a simpler way. Thank you for your thoughts.

```swift
struct HexagonParameters {
    
    struct Segment {
        let line: CGPoint
        let curve: CGPoint
        let control: CGPoint
    }
    
    static let adjustment: CGFloat = 0.085
    
    static let topSholdHt = 0.13
    static let botSholdHt = 0.87
    
    static let segments = [
        
        Segment( // top center
                line:    CGPoint(x: 0.80, y: topSholdHt), // top right
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 0.20, y: topSholdHt), // top left
                control: CGPoint(x: 0.50, y: 0.00) // center / peak
            ),
            Segment( // upper left
                line:    CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.20),
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.30),
                control: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.23)
            ),
            Segment( // lower left
                line:    CGPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.70),
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.80),
                control: CGPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.78)
            ),
            Segment( // bottom center
                line:    CGPoint(x: 0.20, y: botSholdHt),
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 0.80, y: botSholdHt),
                control: CGPoint(x: 0.50, y: 1.00)
            ),
            Segment(    // lower right
                line:    CGPoint(x: 0.95, y: 0.80),
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.70),
                control: CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.78)
            ),
            Segment(
                line:    CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.30),
                curve:   CGPoint(x: 0.95, y: 0.20),
                control: CGPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.23)
            )
    ]
    
}
```

The struct is used like this

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            var width: CGFloat = 300.0
            let height = width
            path.move(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: width * 0.95,
                    y: height * 0.20
                )
            )
            
            HexagonParameters.segments.forEach { segment in
                path.addLine(
                    to: CGPoint(
                        x: width * segment.line.x,
                        y: height * segment.line.y
                    )
                )
                
                path.addQuadCurve(
                    to: CGPoint(
                        x: width * segment.curve.x,
                        y: height * segment.curve.y),
                    control: CGPoint(
                        x: width * segment.control.x,
                        y: height * segment.control.y
                    )
                )
            }
        }
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .padding(.horizontal)

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you solved it yourself, the shape looks great. You could also create a custom ```Shape```, but it would probably be a similar amount of code and no simpler. When you say, it is not perfectly rounded, are you actually wanting to smooth out the corners so that it sweeps from the corner to the middle peak without an inverted arc near the corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it looks like you solved it yourself, your code produces the shape in the question.

However, you remarked that your shape was:

> not perfectly rounded

So I am wondering if you are trying to achieve a smoother shape which does not have the inverted arcs near the corners?

Assuming this is the case, here is how it could be solved with a custom `Shape`. I wouldn't say it's any simpler to maintain than what you originally had, but at least it demonstrates a different approach.

```swift
struct Lozenge: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let cornerRadius = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) * 0.1
        let middleHeight = rect.size.height * 0.15
        let cornerAngleRadians = atan2(rect.size.width, rect.size.height - (2 * middleHeight))
        let cornerAngleDegrees = cornerAngleRadians * 180 / Double.pi

        var path = Path()
        var x = rect.minX
        var y = rect.minY + cornerRadius + middleHeight
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))

        // Top-left corner
        x += cornerRadius
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(-180),
            endAngle: .degrees(-180 + cornerAngleDegrees),
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Middle bump on top
        x = rect.maxX - cornerRadius + (cornerRadius * cos(cornerAngleRadians))
        y = rect.minY + middleHeight + cornerRadius - (cornerRadius * sin(cornerAngleRadians))
        path.addQuadCurve(
            to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY - middleHeight)
        )
        // Top-right corner
        x = rect.maxX - cornerRadius
        y = rect.minY + cornerRadius + middleHeight
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(-cornerAngleDegrees),
            endAngle: .degrees(0),
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Bottom-right corner
        y = rect.maxY - cornerRadius - middleHeight
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(0),
            endAngle: .degrees(cornerAngleDegrees),
            clockwise: false
        )
        // Lower bump on bottom
        x = rect.minX + cornerRadius - (cornerRadius * cos(cornerAngleRadians))
        y = rect.maxY - middleHeight - cornerRadius + (cornerRadius * sin(cornerAngleRadians))
        path.addQuadCurve(
            to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY + middleHeight)
        )
        // Bottom-left corner
        x = rect.minX + cornerRadius
        y = rect.maxY - cornerRadius - middleHeight
        path.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y),
            radius: cornerRadius,
            startAngle: .degrees(180 - cornerAngleDegrees),
            endAngle: .degrees(180),
            clockwise: false
        )
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Lozenge()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 3)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

[image: Lozenge]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to figure out how to do this with addArc and just couldn't get it.  Wow! I can see where i was going wrong now as well.

Comment: This was a HUGE HELP - Thank You !!!

Comment: You're welcome Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: @Westsider There was an error in the formula for converting radians to degrees (it was using + instead of *). Corrected now.

Comment: Ahh - great catch - Than you so much !!!