# Cut corner of image and border. SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can’t figure out how to cut off the corner of an image and border? I know that you can use `.cornerRadius` but I only need to crop one top right corner and the same corner of the border. Look at the image I attached  [image] I'm using iOS 15

Comment: Use `clipShape` and define your own `Shape`

Comment: @jnpdx I don't know with Shape, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested in a comment, a custom `Shape` would probably be the easiest way to achieve this effect. This would also allow you to use `.round` as the style for the line joins, which would give more rounded corners.

However, if you are happy with sharp corners, you can do it by applying overlays to the image:

- first an overlay is applied to cut off the corner
- then a border is added to the image
- then another overlay is added to cut off the corner again, this time with a border on the overlay.

The final result needs to be clipped, so that the parts of the overlays that extend beyond the frame are cut off.

```swift
var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "ladybug")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(.red)
        .padding(10)
        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(30))
                .offset(x: 25, y: -65)
        }
        .border(Color.blue, width: 3)
        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3)
                .background(Color.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(30))
                .offset(x: 33, y: -70)
        }
        .clipped()
}
```

The offsets were found using a little trial and error.

[image: ladybug]

Comment: Thank you very much, it turns out this example will only work with a certain image size?

Comment: @Denis It depends how you size the overlays. If you use the same fixed size as here (100 pt) then it will work on all images that are at least this big, provided the padding and line widths are also the same. Otherwise, you could make the overlay size dependent on the image size, padding and line width, in which case the offsets would also need to be scaled accordingly.

Comment: It's strange that Apple hasn't yet made a way to do this like .cornerRadius or maybe I don't know, I'm just not familiar with Shape. Your method works fine for me, thanks for spending your time on this. :)

Comment: @Denis Thanks for accepting the answer! The technique that Apple provides is to use a `Shape`, which is not that difficult really, especially since this shape is built up using straight lines. See [SwiftUI Custom Rounded RectangleShape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77311003/20386264) for an example of how a shape can be used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this)